# Mobile Safari (iOS): <input type="file"> does no longer convert + downscale video

Tags: ios, html5-video, mobile-safari

With one of the recent iOS releases, Apple seems to have changed the behavior of `<input type="file">` when it comes to picking videos from the camera roll. It used to be that before the video file was handed over to the website, iOS would downscale the video to 720p and also convert it to H.264 (AVC).

Alas, this is no longer the case. Safari now forwards the video files "as is" and does not transcode them. In particular, it does not convert HEVC-encoded videos to H.264.

Is there a way to make `<input type="file">` still transcode/downscale user-selected videos, ie., revert to the old behavior? I tried adding `accept="video/*"`, but to no avail...

Answer (score 4):

Answer to myself: turns out iOS *does* convert HEVC-encoded recordings to H.264 (and downscales them to 720p), but only if the `multiple` attribute is **not set** on the `<input type="file">` element.

Once the `multiple` attribute is set, the HTML input element will receive the original HEVC-encoded videos and no compression/downscaling happens before they are handed to the website.

Comment: Thanks man! This is such a weird behaviour. I run a video platform and want to allow users to upload their videos in full resolution. This workaround is so unintuitive, great find!

Answer (score 0):

(Since I can't make a comment on your answer, I am writing my response here.) In August of 2022 my testing on iPhone 8 plus running Safari on iOS 15.4.1 shows that the "multiple"  attribute does NOT control whether the video compression before uploading happens. It happens each time when selecting a single file or multiple files.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).